# Time related function execution in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an interesting thought.

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE
    field1 <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600
AND field2 > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1000
```

Will the three time stamp may result in different values .. or if there is a chance that MySQL  may intelligently evaluate these once and use the result in all three of these ?

Comment: _if there is a chance that MySQL may intelligently evaluate these once and use the result in all three of these_. I've tested it out of curiosity. Called  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` **5030** times in a query and it took **206 ** Seconds and the results are all same.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this is not properly documented for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.  For `NOW()`, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is quite clear:

> `NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger,
>   NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement
>   began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which
>   returns the exact time at which it executes.

I *think* `UNIX_TIMETAMP()` follows the same rules as `NOW()`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to repeat unix_timestamp().

```
SET @now = NOW();
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = @now
WHERE
   field1 <= @now - 600
   AND field2 > @now - 1000;
```